# Finding the maximum allowable value for generic type T

Tags: rust

I am implementing a merge sort which will sort an array of type `T`. In my `merge` method, the algorithm calls for the the last element of the left and right list be **positive infinity**. How can I get the maximum value a given data type can hold?

```
fn merge<T: PartialOrd + Copy + std::fmt::Debug>(p: usize, q: usize, r: usize, array: &mut Vec<T>) {
    let left_size: usize = q - p;
    let right_size: usize = r - q;

    let mut left: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
    let mut right: Vec<T> = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..left_size {
        left.push(array[p + i]);
    }

    for i in 0..right_size {
        right.push(array[q + i]);
    }

    left.push(T::max_value()); //where I would put the max value
    right.push(T::max_value()); //where I would put the max value

    let mut i: usize = 0;
    let mut j: usize = 0;

    for k in p..r {
        if left[i] <= right[j] {
            array[k] = left[i];
            i += 1;
        } else {
            array[k] = right[j];
            j += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `array: &mut Vec<T>` — that is **not** an "array". An array has a size known at compile time. See also [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423).

Comment: FWIW, there's lots of little non-idiomatic points with this code. You may want to consider [posting your working code to Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way of doing that with the standard library at this time. One way to solve it would be make your own trait, add another trait bound to `merge` and implement your trait for the types you are expecting.

The specific trait implementation for `u32` would then return `std::u32::MAX` and so on for the other types.

Here is a [discussion from earlier this year](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/trait-for-a-maximum-value-of-a-type/2238).

As [*oli_obk - ker* pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904954/finding-the-maximum-allowable-value-for-generic-type-t#comment82778257_47905568) below, the `num` crate already has such a trait: [`Bounded`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.Bounded.html).

Comment: you're completely right. There is the `num` crate which already has such a trait: [`Bounded`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.Bounded.html)

Comment: Oh that is nice and good to know. Doesn't turn up on rustdoc of course. I have to extend my searches to crates more often.

Comment: perfect. Thanks, I implemented the trait bound and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

For a generic upper bound you could also wrap the type in an enum:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug)]
enum UpperBounded<T> {
    Value(T),
    Max,
}
```

The [derived order is documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#derivable) to sort `Value(_)` before `Max`.

`UpperBounded<T>` can then be used for the `left` and `right` vectors.